# How to fix Ruby 2.7 deprecation warning for "last argument"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I created a Rails demo application after installing Ruby 2.7.1.

`rails test` executes without errors, but spits outs a series of sprockets gem warnings:

```
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/sprockets-4.0.0/lib/sprockets/base.rb:119: warning: Using the last argument as keyword parameters is deprecated; maybe ** should be added to the call
```

They're warnings, so nothing has blown up but it's disconcerting. I understand Sprockets is being phased out in favor of Webpacker and wonder if I should tolerate this until it's safe to remove Sprockets from my Gemfile.

Here's the setup:

- Ubuntu 18.04 LTS
- Lenovo ideapad laptop
- Ruby 2.7.1p83 (x86_64-linux)
- rbenv 1.0.0
- Rails 6.0.3
- RubyGems 3.1.3

Answer (score 2):

It seems to be a [known issue](https://github.com/rails/sprockets/issues/659) and is already fixed in the master branch, and is going to be fixed in 4.0.1.

To summarize, Sprockets is not yet fully ready for Ruby 2.7